# Deleted Datastore entries reappear

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleted Datastore entries reappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594224/deleted-datastore-entries-reappear)

I've encountered a strange problem using the Datastore on Google App Engine. There is a set of exactly 54,625 Datastore entities of one kind that reappear after they have been deleted.

I tried to delete all entities of this kind multiple times by using the Datastore Admin interface as well as the mapreduce library with a self-defined handler:

```
def clear_datastore(entity):

    yield op.db.Delete(entity)
```

However, each time new entities of this kind are put into the Datastore the once removed entities reappear. I have no clue on what's going on. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any task running in the task queue?

Comment: It's impossible to help given the information provided - there are thousands of apps _not_ experiencing this issue, and you haven't provided any information that would distinguish your app from them.