# Deleted Datastore entries reappear

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'd like to re-open [Deleted Datastore entries reappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585263/deleted-datastore-entries-reappear) as a registered user. Can the old question be deleted?

I'll try to be more specific this time. I'm experiencing the following problem:

Initially I put N entities of the same kind into the Datastore like that:

```
datastore_entity = MyModel(model_property=property_value)
datastore_entity.put()
```

Afterwards I delete them. I have used the Datastore Admin interface as well as a self-defined handler for the mapreduce library in order to do so. The deleted entities do not appear neither in the Datastore viewer nor in the Datastore Admin view.

When I put even just one new single entity of this kind into the Datastore, the old Datastore entities reappear in the Datastore Admin view while the new entity does not (judging by the number of entities). On the contrary, the Datastore viewer correctly reflects the Datastore state. A query also returns only the newly created entity.

There are no tasks at the time the new entity is being put into the Datastore.

I'm also not encountering this problem on my local machine where I'm using the --clean_datastore option when starting the server.

Comment: this seems more of misunderstanding datastore, an registered applications uses different datastore altogether, You might have deleted other application's data...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Datastore Admin and Datastore Statistics are not "live". The Datastore viewer offers a live view.

Check "Entity statistics last updated..." and you will notice the difference.

If the old entities are not visible in the Datastore viewer - no need to worry. Eventually the statistics will be updated.